# What is #pragma weak_import?

Tags: c++, c, pragma

And what is the best way to look up these pragma information in the internet? Google search comes up with a lot of noise (mainly the occurrence of the pragma in various source code repositories)

Comment: `#pragma`s are compiler-specific. It may help your search if you also specify what compiler you're using and/or platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's something for Mac OS X, documented here:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/tn2064/_index.html

Comment: I see! So it is about the weak linking feature in osx!

Answer (score 2):

From what I can tell, and based on documentation from [Apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Concepts/WeakLinking.html) (under the "Marking Symbols for Weak Linking" section), `weak_import` when used as an attribute specifies that a symbol is weakly-linked, either in a framework or something else.  I don't know how it applies as a pragma, but I would *guess* it specifies that every symbol in that translation unit is weakly-linked.

Comment: Just means that the if the function impl is not found , then it will be stubbed(Which is a weak function). To prevent build errors.

Answer (score 0):

"This directive is used to specify diverse options to the compiler. These options are specific for the platform and the compiler you use. Consult the manual or the reference of your compiler for more information on the possible parameters that you can define with #pragma.

If the compiler does not support a specific argument for #pragma, it is ignored - no error is generated."

http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/preprocessor/

So, according to this, you'd have to look up the documentation for your compiler to see what that specific option does, due to this the best way to look up pragma information on the internet would be based on the compiler you use.

Answer (score 0):

From MSDN reference [Pragma directives](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d9x1s805%28VS.71%29.aspx):

"Each implementation of C and C++ supports some features unique to its host machine or operating system. Some programs, for instance, need to exercise precise control over the memory areas where data is placed or to control the way certain functions receive parameters. The #pragma directives offer a way for each compiler to offer machine- and operating system-specific features while retaining overall compatibility with the C and C++ languages. Pragmas are machine- or operating system-specific by definition, and are usually different for every compiler."